# Update table after executing Alter Table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to execute this code:

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR select_grupos IS SELECT * FROM grupo_musical;
    grupo grupo_musical%ROWTYPE;
    contador NUMBER;
    TYPE ciudades IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
    capitales_vascas ciudades;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE GRUPO_MUSICAL ADD ciudad_origen VARCHAR2(30)';  
    capitales_vascas := ciudades('Bilbao', 'Donostia', 'Gasteiz');
    contador := 0;
    FOR grupo IN select_grupos LOOP
        grupo.ciudad_origen := capitales_vascas(MOD(contador, 3) + 1); 
        UPDATE grupo_musical SET ROW=grupo WHERE id_grupo=grupo.id_grupo;
        contador := contador + 1; 
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

It says that I have to declare 'ciudad_origen'. I understand that is because when I create the cursor, Alter table is not finished. Is it any other way I can program this?

Thank you.

Comment: WHY do you alter table inside procedure ? you declare cursor above without the column . and alter the table down there...

Comment: I'm teacher, just trying to explain what EXECUTE IMMEDIATE can do

Comment: `ALTER TABLE` is *finished* immediately after the *execution*; at time of the *compiling* the PL/SQL block the `ALTER TABLE` was therefore *not even started*.

Comment: _"I'm teacher, just trying to explain what EXECUTE IMMEDIATE can do"_  Then you need to find a better example.

Comment: @AG this turned out to be a great example for teaching dynamic SQL. It demonstrates a consequence of PL/SQL being a compiled language, as this isn't a script that just runs each command as it finds it. The compiler checks references to database objects, and when that fails the whole block is invalid and can never even start. Anything that refers to `grupo_musical.ciudad_origen` needs to be dynamic as well, and you'll find out whether it's valid or not at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that is because when I create the cursor, Alter table is not finished

Exactly. That's why dynamic SQL is *evil*. Why would you want to alter the table in PL/SQL? What's wrong with altering it at SQL level and writing a "normal" code afterwards?

If you insist on doing it that way, then you'll have to switch **everything** to dynamic SQL because - as you noticed - you can't reference a column that doesn't exist yet.

So, why is it *evil*? Because dynamic SQL is difficult to debug and maintain. Mind all single quotes you have to escape (or use the q-quoting mechanism), poorly formatted code (no GUI built-in formatter will touch code within quotes which are - as far as it is concerned - just a *string*), etc.

I suggest you alter table first, write PL/SQL code next.

Comment: This. Do not touch dynamic SQL with a 5 foot pole, unless there is no other way of getting data. Better to write an SQL query that is 100 lines long and it'll still perform better.